# Alert Dialog stays open through back button push

Tags: android, flutter, provider

I'm having a little error I can't seem to figure out, and I believe it's due to my Alert Dialog implementation.  I'm using the flutter Provider package, and opening my Dialog like this:

```
  _openSearchHistory(
      BuildContext context, TextEditingController searchController) {
    final searchModel = Provider.of<SearchModel>(context, listen: false);
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => ChangeNotifierProvider<SearchModel>.value(
              value: searchModel,
              child: DialogSearchHistory(
                searchHistory: searchModel.searchHistory,
                searchController: searchController,
              ),
            ));
  }
```

The problem is when on android and the user presses the back button, the Dialog does not close, but the page behind the Dialog pops back a page.  I have a close button on the Dialog that successfully closes the dialog, but I want users to be able to use the back button for a better experience.  The Dialog does close if the user clicks outside of it as well.  I've tried wrapping the Dialog with WillPopScope, but it does not get called on a back button press.

Could anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong here?

I have tried wrapping the Widget in the calling method with WillPopScope

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) => ChangeNotifierProvider<SearchModel>.value(
          value: searchModel,
          child: WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              return Future.value(false);
            },
            child: DialogSearchHistory(
              searchHistory: searchModel.searchHistory,
              searchController: searchController,
            ),
          ),
        ));
```

As well as wrapping the Alert Dialog itself in the build function

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: AlertDialog(
        backgroundColor: kCardColor,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
        ),...
```

Neither have worked.  The page behind the Dialog pops back, but the Dialog stays put.  onWillPop is never hit by the debugger

Comment: Can you show me what you've written inside the ```onWillPop``` method of ```WillPopScope```?

Comment: ...              child: WillPopScope(
                onWillPop: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  return Future.value(false);
                },

Comment: Can you check my answer @Swisscheese

Comment: Also try to wrap the route (ex: wrap the Scaffold) with WillPopScope instead of Alert Dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the application has multiple Navigator objects, it may be necessary to call Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(result) to close the dialog rather than just Navigator.pop(context, result).

I hope this will close the alert dialog If you have multiple navigator objects. Give it a try

```
onWillPop: (){
  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
  return  Future.value(false);
},
```

**OR**

Try `Navigator.pop(context);`, this will call internally `Navigator.of(context).pop()` method.

Official Implementation of `Navigator.pop()` method.

```
static void pop<T extends Object>(BuildContext context, [ T result ]) {
  Navigator.of(context).pop<T>(result);
}
```

Doc - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, but you're missing the main problem.  onWillPop is never called,  so any code inside of it doesn't matter at this point.  I can't seem to figure out why onWillPop is never called, I thought it had to do with the way I was presenting the Alert Dialog, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Surely the onWillPop will be called if you click the back button. You just need to wrap the whole screen (wrap the scaffold) with WillPopScope instead of just wrapping the alert dialog @Swisscheese

Comment: Wrapping the entire scaffold with it does indeed close the dialog window.  Problem is it messes up any further backwards navigation the user would do.  I can just add a check to see if the dialog is open and should be able to call "Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop('dialog');" to only close it.  Just seems janky to me and like I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but setting useRootNavigator to false inside showDialog worked for me.

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  useRootNavigator: false,
  builder: (context) {
    return AlertDialog();
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there i face similar issue and the below method worked for me as Vinoth vino tell wrap your page in WillPopScope widget and try to add pop function there like

```
body: WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: (){
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    return  Future.value(false);
    },
  child:...your code
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I tried wrapping the Widget like from the method call, as well as wrapping the Alert Dialog in build